# Парсер таблиц в формате pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, pdf

Всем доброго времени суток, проблема такова:

У меня около 40-50 тысяч 1 страничных pdf файлов, в них таблицы одинаковой структуры. Надо из этих таблиц спарсить данные в JSON или xml, ну или в листы и словари что бы легче было работать, делать математические операций.

Пробовал пакеты `tabula` и `pdf-table-extract`. Не дали ожидаемого результата.

Пример таблицы:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Python версия 3.6.1 Anaconda 64 bit.

Операционная система Windows 7 64 bit.

Подскажите, как можно спарсить такую структуру. Думал вытащить все символы из файла и обрезать по кусочкам этот длинный стринг, но это очень долго и в некоторых файлах много пустых ячеек.

Comment: Ваша таблица адово большая. Ее размер навевает мысли о том, что вам на биржу фриланса. Попробуйте изолировать проблему, используя простой пример. Приведите пример попроще для входа, а также ожидаемый результат.

Comment: `Не дали ожидаемого результата` - вы можете подробнее описать - что не так?